# How to properly use a per-test setup function that returns a value in unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

For each of my tests in a `unittest.TestCase` suite, I need to do some setup: run a function that returns a different value for each test (depending on some properties of each test that are passed as arguments to the setup function).

There is the `setUp()` hook that I could use, but it does not return a value and does not accept arguments. But let's say arguments aren't important in this case.

What strategy is recommended?

- Creating a custom setup function to use inside each test case
- Using `setUp()` with global variables
- Using `setUp()` with class or instance variables

Comment: The recommended strategy is calling the function to get the return value. It is unclear to me how `setUp` and global, class or instance variables are relevant here.

Comment: `setUp` returns `None`, but I need a setup function that returns a value. The problem is whether to not use `setUp` at all and make your own setup function and call it in every test method or use `setUp` but set some global variables in it.

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to "set some global variables".

Comment: So as to have common objects needed for each test, say lists, but each list would contain different objects depending on the test.

Comment: Why would you want them to be common?

Comment: For example, I have a list of berries for each test. Test1 works with `['cherry', 'blueberry']`, Test2 works with `['raspberry']`. Often resources like this are global for the module/suite. Each call to a setup function would assign a new the value for the list.

Comment: Well you might have a reason to do it that way. As I read your question it looks just pointless but the question is too vague and I might be missing something relevant to your actual scenario. Adding a concrete example might help.

Answer (score 2):

I follow the general strategy of, if a variable will be used in multiple test functions, I define it in the `setUp()`. If it will only be used once local to a specific function, define it in that function.

Take the following example:

Say I have a python module in package `program` called `list_utils.py` and in `list_utils.py` I have the following functions:

```
def list_to_string(mylist):
    """ Takes a list of strings and joins them into a single string.
    """
    return ' '.join(mylist)

def list_extender(mylist, extend_item):
    return mylist.extend(extend_item)
```

Then I setup my unittest script with specifying `mytestlist` because it will be used in multiple test functions:

```
from program import list_utils as lu

class TestListUtils(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    A subclass of unittest to test list_utils.py
    """
    def setUp(self):
        self.mytestlist = ['Hi', 'there']

    def test_list_to_string(self):
        """
        Ensures my list is converted to string
        """
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(lu.list_to_string(self.mytestlist), string))
    def test_list_extender(self):
        """
        Ensures list is extended when argument is passed.
        """
        mylocalvariable = 'Adam'
        self.assertTrue(lu.list_extender(self.mytestlist, mylocalvariable)[-1] == 'Adam')

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You see that for `list_extender` I passed in `mylocalvariable` because I would only use it in the scope of that function, but `mytestlist` was defined in `setUp` because I used it multiple times. By following this general approach, you shouldn't bloat your `setUp` too much, and you also won't have to re-instantiate variables at each specific unittest if they will be used multiple times.

Comment: Thanks! This looks nice, but what if `mytestlist` had to have different elements for each test, depending on the requirements?

Comment: This answer covers that. If you have something you need to change in each test, then make it local to the test. If something will be used in multiple tests add it to setUp. I feel like that is pretty clear in my answer. A list is no longer the same list if you change its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Note my destinction between setup and `Setup` below: Each test has to so some setup activities, but these are not necessarily put into the `Setup` method.

My preference is that each test function should be easily understood by itself.  I don't want to look at test code wondering "where does this value suddenly come from" or the like.  Which means, I avoid a common `Setup` method but instead use helper functions / methods that also have descriptive names.  To be more precise:

- If a test case needs a specific setup, I normally embed it directly into the test.
- If a subset of the test cases have an identical or similar setup, I consider creating a helper method to extract the common parts.  The name of that helper method should be descriptive, like `makeTrafficLightInGreenState` for a helper factory to produce a specific type of traffic light object.  In this example I could then also have `makeTrafficLightInRedState` for a different group of tests.  I find this preferrable over a common `Setup` method which just creates both the green and the red traffic light: In the end you get confused which part of `Setup` is relevant for which test.  Certainly, when writing your helper methods, you are also free to give them parameters, which could in the traffic light example result in 'makeTrafficLightInState(green)'.  But, which approach to choose here is situation specific.
- Even if *all* tests have something in common, like the creation of a certain object, I prefer putting this in a descriptively named helper method rather than relying on the implicit call to `Setup`.
- Sometimes I also use `Setup`, but only for activities that are not necessary for understanding the logic of the test cases.  For example, if there is some original state that needs to be preserved at the beginning of the test cases and to be restored afterwards, this could be put into `Setup` without any negative impact on the readability of the individual test cases.

In your case, you seem to already have a function with parameters that is suited to deliver test case specific data.  I would simply call that function from each test case that needs it.  Or, if calling that function is not simple (you have to create additional objects as arguments for it or the like), again put it into a helper method.